# Can we show the feed of a facebook GROUP on my wesite?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have a private group in Facebook and I want to show whatever is posted in this group to be displayed in a page of my website .

Facebook group : http://www.facebook.com/groups/ghyfoodlovers/

Webpage : http://guwahatifoodie.com/facebook/

The website is hosted in Wordpress and the plugin I am using works perfectly fine for a page , but not for a group . Also I tried to make the privacy " Public " but its not possible for a group with more than 250 members .

Answer (score 0):

Please give the [facebook graph api documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/group/feed) a look.

> /{group-id}/feed
>
> The feed of posts (including status updates) and links published to this group.

Your group id and an valid access token should do the trick.

To experiment with the Graph API you could use the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)